# What actually happens when you use templates?

Tags: c++, templates

I am slightly confused with the concepts with templates. Namely if you have a function like this:

```
template<typename T>
void DoubleValue(T &param)
{
    param *= 2;
}
```

How does the compiler know what types I am allowed to pass to this function? Does it test with all known types if the code works with that type? Does this have performance issues?

Comment: The compiler doesn't do anything until you actually try to do something, at which point the validity is evaluated.

Comment: So would that result in a compile time error or a run time error?

Comment: It all happens at compile time.

Comment: That's not a function. That's a function *template*.

Comment: Have you *tried* anything and observed your compiler's diagnostics?

Comment: think of templates not as actual code but as ... well as template ;) It only gets turned into code, one you instantiate it with a template parameter. E.g. only with the code you show the compiler will not do anything (it is not code). Try e.g. `DoubleValue<int>` or `DoubleValue<std::string>` and you will see the effect of what you are asking for.

Comment: And no, C++ templates have no effect on runtime performance. They can slow *compilation* down, however.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant and drastically increase target binary size if you're not careful.

Comment: @Qix: and occasionally decrease it by supporting dead code elimination and type-specific optimisations that runtime-polymorphic equivalent code can't (which are also ways in which they can affect runtime performance; our favourite Croissant's assertion's a little dodgy on that).

Comment: @TonyD well, assuming a good programmer wouldn't do that otherwise ;)

Comment: @KierenPearson: templates provide what's known as Parametric Polymorphism, and Duck Typing - you can try instantiating them with any parameters and if the code inside makes sense for the parameter types/constants, you're good.  C++17 might finally introduce Concepts, which would let the template parameters imply expectations of the types/constants with which they're instantiated, with some documentary benefit, and generally improved compiler error messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Contrary to generics in Java or C# (where a type parameter acts like a `boost::any`, i.e. a compiler-secured, runtime-checked `void*`), a [class/function] template is not a [class/function]. It is used to generate an ad-hoc [class/function] at the *point of instantiation* (not to be confused with object instantiation).

The instantiation can be explicit :

```
// Hey compiler, please generate code for DoubleValue<int>.
template void DoubleValue<int>(int &param);
```

... or implicit :

```
int main() {
    // Hey compiler, I want to call DoubleValue<float>.
    // Please generate the code if it's not done already.
    return DoubleValue(1.5f);
}
```

All of this is done at compile-time.

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh well. I think I can just dump that part, it was a bit redundant anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler does nothing until you actually use (read: instantiate) your template, e.g:

```
SomeType x;
DoubleValue(x);
```

At this moment compiler tries to generate code for the function `DoubleValue(SomeType&)`. The compilation succedes if the code can be generated (in your example if the `SomeType` type has an operator `*=` defined).

Another example:

```
template<typename T>
void SomeFunc(T param)
{
    param.foo();
}

SomeType x;
SomeFunc(x);
```

Instantiation of `SomeFunc` will succeed if `SomeType` has a method `foo` - if it doesn't, the compiler will exit with an error. Sometimes it is called *compile-time polymorphism*.

I short: templates are a convenient way of generating code on demand (nothing happens until you actually `use` (read: instantiate) the template).

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't test it with all types . the compiler generate only code with type you're going to use for you treatment and of if it is not possible you will receive a compilation error. Template  is static polymorphism made to avoid rewriting same code for multiple types
So for example :

```
  int x=5;
  DoubleValue(x);
```

the compiler will only generate the function with int & as signature

```
void DoubleValue(int &param)
{
    param *= 2;
}
```

Comment: Before optimizing that whole function/call out completely :)